# how to add checkbox intems in to data base in one row

Tags: php, html

i am crated form,

```
<td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="sweet" />
                     Sweet<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value=" sour" />
                       Sour<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value=" creamy" />
                       Creamy<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="mode[]" id="mode" value="bland" />
                      Bland<br />                
                </td>
```

and php code is,

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($mode); $i++)
{
    $emode = mysql_real_escape_string($mode[$i]);

    $query  =<<<EOF
INSERT INTO frutesdetails(fruitname,fruitcolor,seasonfrom,seasonto,fruitetaste,fruitbenefit) 
VALUES ('{$fruitname}', '{$category}',
        '{$startdate}','{$enddate}','{$emode}','{$fruitbenefit}')
EOF;
$insertresults = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

}
```

i got all the record but not in one recod ,if i check 2 check box i get two records in two different row not in single row

Comment: What? "if i check 2 check box i get two, like three" makes no sense. This question is very low quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it all stored in one record, first remove the `for()` loop. Then you have a couple options take your pick:

```
$emode = mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($mode));
$emode = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($mode));
$emode = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',',$mode));
```

Then you just have decode on the way out.

Comment: Wait are you wanting all of them stored in one record Or are you wanting one record for each box checked?

Comment: how can i use this code inside my code?

Comment: Get rid of the for loop. Then replace `$emode = mysql_real_escape_string($mode[$i]);` with one of the options I listed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem is that

- your PHP code inserts one row into the database for each checkbox selected, but
- you want it to insert one row containing all checkbox selections.

But that's exactly what you're doing in your code - you're looping over `$mode` and executing your `mysql_query` call for each element in `$mode`. If you want all selections in the same row, then let your `$emode` be some representation of all selections instead of just one of them, and get rid of that for loop.

Comment: what is the solution can you tell me